# Adding a default before() function for all the test cases (Mocha)

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js

I'm writing functions for my node.js server using TDD(Mocha). For connecting to the database I'm doing

```
before(function(done){
  db.connect(function(){
      done();
   });
});
```

and I'm running the test cases using `make test` and have configured my makefile to run all the js files in that particular folder using `mocha *.js`

But for each `js` file I'll have to make a separate connection to the database, otherwise my test cases fail since they do not share common scope with other test files.

So the question is, Is there anything like `beforeAll()` that would just simply connect once to the database and then run all the test cases? Any help/suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your db connection as a module that each of the Mocha test modules imports.

```
var db = require('./db');
```

A good database interface will queue commands you send to it before it has finished connecting.  You can use that to your advantage here.

In your `before` call, simply do something that amounts to a `no op`.  In SQL that would be something simple like a raw query of `SELECT 1`.  You don't care about the result.  The return of the query just signifies that the database is ready.

Since each Mocha module uses the same database module, it'll only connect once.

Use this in each of your test modules:

```
before(function(done) {
  db.no_op(done);
});
```

Then define `db.no_op` to be a function that performs the `no op` and takes a callback function.

Comment: I previously had the same thoughts but was just thinking of more "mocha" way of doing this, like a mocha specific function that i can configure or something like that. But anyways you're solution works. Thanks and +1 for the prompt response.